# $_POST data not being sent

Tags: php, html, forms, post, http-post

I have a simple form which was working and now im finding the post data isnt being sent and i can't see the problem

```
<form role="form" name="challengeform" action="scripts/arena_setup.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to attack this player?');">
    <input type="hidden" name="member_id" value="<? echo $member_id;?>">
    <input type="image" src="img/map/attack.png" alt="Attack" />
</form>
```

which is being handled by

```
if(isset($_POST['challengeform'])){ 
...
}else{ echo 'error'; }
```

it always shows the error due to the post data being missing but i just cant see what i've done. Any ideas?

Comment: forms don't use name attributes. Use the hidden attribute instead.

Comment: And even if they would, the form itself is not a value that could appear inside the `$_POST` super global variable. The _contents_ of the form do. So `$_POST['member_id']` and `$_POST['image']` in this case.

Comment: ^ he took the words right out of my mouth ;-) I only put it "in a nutshell".

Comment: @arkascha Agreed, but seeing your edited comment about the `$_POST['image']`, that won't work, since it sends x,y ;-) and `isset()` won't work with the image input.

Comment: im such an idiot, its been a long run coding tonight im starting to make stupid mistakes. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['challengeform']))
```

Form names are not part of the POST data. Only fields within the form.

Try testing for the field itself

```
if(isset($_POST['member_id']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't write the name of the form. Just write input's name to get the data. Ex:

```
$var = $_POST['member_id'];
```